# store data from database in a PHP array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, row

There's a table in an SQL database with a row "x" with numerous fields. I need to get these fields and store each one in a php array like this:

```
array_value[0] = item 0 in row;
array_value[1] = item 1 in row;
array_value[2] = item 2 in row;
...
```

How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Did you even bother TRYING to look at the standard documentation, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php ?

Comment: Thanks, I found what I've searching ;D